# How To Design XML Layout for Support All Screen?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-screen-support

I need Design XML Screen Support to all screen,how can i design like support screen.And how can i divided button size ,text view size for all screen,image size button image size like,how can i understand this.Any one can help me guys

Comment: You need to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Create folders like specified in the image]

You have to create folders with the following names:

**1) layout**

**2) layout-large**

3) layout-xlarge

4) layout-480x320

Create your layout in xml and adjust the layout settings in other related layouts. You place xml layout files (Which are same in terms of name) in all of these folders and design them accordingly.

Comment: its correct or using weight for layout this is right? which is better @NunChai

Comment: The above is officially documented here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all use relative layout or linear layout to support your app in all screen,

then paste your images which you are using in all folder

**drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi**

and then create folder like

**layout-small, layout-medium, layout-large, and layout-xlarge**

and put your all XML file in this all folder.

Then android will take care of your devices.

Comment: i know that.. i need which one use weight for layout this is right? or  Create layout-large ,layout-small etc.. which one is better..

Comment: Which one is better, read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771486/is-it-good-to-use-layout-weights-and-relativelayout-for-multiple-screens